# MSI with Windows 11 installed unable to log in error 0xd000a002

Tags: windows, command-line, laptop, installation, windows-11

I'm having a problem with my MSI Summit E13FlipEvo A12MT-019IT laptop with Windows 11 installed. For a few days I haven't been able to log in by entering my pin and password even though I know that they are certainly correct. Furthermore, by entering the right password I always get the error code 0xd000a002 and the only screens I have available to navigate are: lock screen, bios and recovery section. Even in this last section I tried to use various commands by starting the cmd but none of these manage to make me change the password, disable its entry or start the factory reset, these are promptly blocked, giving me error after error. I'm looking for a way to at least restore windows, even if it seems impossible

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/my-laptop-shows-error-code-0xd000a002/f6e18621-89d6-4316-8a87-033ca6c30ea7

Comment: Can you boot into Safe mode? Or into Command Prompt mode? Can you login to your Microsoft account on the browser? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: yes, I can boot into safe mode and open the cmd @harrymc

Comment: There are multiple manipulations possible in these modes. But the safest course would be: (1) If System Restore is enabled, rollback to a time before it happened, (2) If you are on Microsoft account, login on the web and change your login options.